# I cannot change the paragraph color in my html

Tags: html, css

```css
p {
  color: #7FE330;
}
```

```html
<p><center> My Paragraph </center></p>
```

I have been trying to change my paragraph color but it is just not working. This code above is what i been doing.

Comment: Can you please try with add `;` at the end of the color code -   `p {color:#7FE330;}`.

Comment: Maybe you are styling ```<center>``` somewhere?

Comment: Also `center` is an **obsolete** element and should no longer be used.

Comment: Further to Paulie-D's Comment the `<center>` element is not a valid child of a `<p>`, therefore the selector won't match.

Comment: Might be other style is overriding.

Comment: No, @Prakash, it's invalid HTML being 'rescued' by the DOM which prevents the selector from matching.

Comment: @DavidThomas, yes got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

```css
p {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <p>test</p>
</center>
```

The `center` tag cannot be encapsulated inside a tag containing text nodes such as `<p>`, or `<span>`.

Changing the order will solve your problem.

It's also important to mention that the `<center>` tag isn't supported in HTML5 and you should use CSS to achieve the desired result according to W3C.

To align the text to the center of the container you can use the following style `text-align:center` instead of the deprecated `center` tag.

```html
<style>
  p {
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
<p>Hello World ;)</p>
```

Comment: Please expand your answer to illustrate how (incredibly easy it is) to "*use CSS to achieve the desired result.*"

Comment: you miss the ">"

Comment: @Jonny: I'm sorry?

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML is broken because the `<p>` element cannot contain a block level element. [Quote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p):

> Paragraphs are block-level elements, and notably will automatically
>   close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing
>   `</p>` tag.

The browser tries to fix your HTML as follows:

[image: element inspector]

The correct solution is to stop using the obsolete `<center>` element and use CSS to center content.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the style of tag p to center.

```html
  <style>
  center {
     color:#7FE330
   }
  </style>
      
 <p><center> My Paragraph </center></p>
```